# How to filter or remove rows that contain values in list in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Below is a dataframe that contains values in a list form. I would like to perform two operations. I would like to remove all the rows that contain year as ['2017', '2018] and I would like to split the ['2017'] rows and ['2018'] rows as separate dataframes.

```
df4 =pd.DataFrame({ 'Key':['12', '180,146','34', '56', '87'], 'Year':[ ['2017', '2018'],['2017'], ['2018'], ['2017','2018'],['2018']]})
```

I couldnt find an option that could perform this when the values itself are inside a list. It would be nice if I could keep the values in the list itself since the rest of the computation is based on them being so. Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create masks for each of the conditions:

```
m_2017_2018 = df4['Year'].apply(lambda x: x == ['2017', '2018'])
m_2017 = df4['Year'].apply(lambda x: x == ['2017'])
m_2018 = df4['Year'].apply(lambda x: x == ['2018'])
```

And then create DataFrames for each of the masks.

```
df4 = df4[~m_2017_2018]
df_2017 = df4[m_2017]
df_2018 = df4[m_2018]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First using str.len get the row you want to keep

```
df1=df4[df4.Year.str.len().eq(1)].copy()
```

Then, using `groupby` split the dataframe into `dict`

```
d={x : y for x , y in df1.groupby(df1.Year.apply(tuple))}
d
Out[680]: 
{('2017',):        Key    Year
 1  180,146  [2017], ('2018',):   Key    Year
 2  34  [2018]
 4  87  [2018]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you store `Year` in your result as integers. Here's one way:

```
df = df4.loc[df4['Year'].map(len).eq(1)]\
        .assign(Year=np.array(df['Year'].values.tolist()).ravel().astype(int))

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Year')))

print(dfs)

{2017:        Key  Year
       1  180,146  2017,

 2018:        Key  Year
       2       34  2018
       4       87  2018}
```